# Adapt this code to highlight all returned matches from search field in an OpenLayers map

Tags: openlayers, mapping, qgis2web, search

I have an OpenLayers map documenting nut trees on my farm. I have a search field to search the type of trees. When a single tree is selected in the search dropdown a tree is highlighted. I would like to adapt the code to have all trees in the dropdown to be highlighted on the map in blue before selecting any individual.
[image]

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
function hasClass(el, cls) {
  return el.className && new RegExp('(\\s|^)' +
    cls + '(\\s|$)').test(el.className);
}

function addClass(elem, className) {
  if (!hasClass(elem, className)) {
    elem.className += ' ' + className;
  }
}

function removeClass(elem, className) {
  var newClass = ' ' + elem.className.replace(/[\t\r\n]/g, ' ') + ' ';
  if (hasClass(elem, className)) {
    while (newClass.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') >= 0) {
      newClass = newClass.replace(' ' + className + ' ', ' ');
    }
    elem.className = newClass.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  }
}

var SearchLayer = (function (Control) {
 function SearchLayer(optOptions) {
  var horseyComponent;
  var select;
  var options = optOptions || {};
  if (optOptions.layer) {
    options.layer = optOptions.layer;
  } else {
    throw new Error('error');
  }
  options.map = optOptions.map;

  var source;
  if (options.layer instanceof ol.layer.Image &&
      options.layer.getSource() instanceof ol.source.ImageVector) {
    source = options.layer.getSource().getSource();
  } else if (options.layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector) {
    source = options.layer.getSource();
  }
  options.colName = optOptions.colName;

  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var toogleHideShowInput = function() {
    var input = document.querySelector('form > .search-layer-input-search');
    if (hasClass(input, 'search-layer-collapsed')) {
      removeClass(input, 'search-layer-collapsed');
    } else {
      input.value = '';
      addClass(input, 'search-layer-collapsed');
      horseyComponent.hide();
      select.getFeatures().clear();
    }
  };

  button.addEventListener('click', toogleHideShowInput, false);
  button.addEventListener('touchstart', toogleHideShowInput, false);

  var form = document.createElement('form');
  form.setAttribute('id', 'random');
  form.onsubmit = undefined;
  // form.setAttribute('action', 'javascript:void(0);');

  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('id', 'ol-search-input');
  var defaultInputClass = ['search-layer-input-search'];
  if (optOptions.collapsed) {
    defaultInputClass.push('search-layer-collapsed');
  }
  input.setAttribute('class', defaultInputClass.join(' '));
  input.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Search ...');
  input.setAttribute('type', 'text');

  form.appendChild(input);

  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'search-layer ol-unselectable ol-control';

  element.appendChild(button);
  element.appendChild(form);

  ol.control.Control.call(this, {
    element: element,
    target: options.target
  });

  select = new ol.interaction.Select({
    id: options.selectId || 'defaultSearchLayer',
    layers: [options.layer],
    condition: ol.events.condition.never
  });

  var map = options.map;

  map.addInteraction(select);

  var typesToZoomToExtent = [
    'MultiPoint',
    'LineString',
    'MultiLineString',
    'MultiPolygon',
    'Polygon'
  ];

  var typesToZoomToCenterAndZoom = [
    'Point'
  ];
  var returnHorsey = function(input, source, map, select, options) {
    horsey(input, {
      source: [{
        list: source.getFeatures().map(function(el, i) {
          if (el.getId() === undefined) {
            el.setId(i);
          }
          return {
            text: el.get(options.colName),
            value: el.getId() // If GeoJSON has an id
          };
        })
      }],
      getText: 'text',
      getValue: 'value',
      predictNextSearch: function(info) {
        var feat = source.getFeatureById(info.selection.value);
        var featType = feat.getGeometry().getType();
        if (typesToZoomToCenterAndZoom.indexOf(featType) !== -1) {
          var newCenter = ol.extent.getCenter(feat.getGeometry().getExtent());
          map.getView().setCenter(newCenter);
          map.getView().setZoom(options.zoom || 12);
        } else if (typesToZoomToExtent.indexOf(featType) !== -1) {
          map.getView().fit(feat.getGeometry().getExtent(), map.getSize());
        }

        select.getFeatures().clear();
        select.getFeatures().push(feat);
      }
    });
  }
  if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
    horseyComponent = returnHorsey(input, source, map, select, options);
  }
  source.once('change', function(e) {
    if (source.getState() === 'ready') {
      horseyComponent = returnHorsey(input, source, map, select, options);
    }
  });
 };
    if (Control) SearchLayer.__proto__ = Control;
    SearchLayer.prototype = Object.create(Control && Control.prototype);
    SearchLayer.prototype.constructor = SearchLayer;
    return SearchLayer;
}(ol.control.Control));
```

I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: What is `horsey`?

Comment: @TomazicM It is a predictive text tool that completes your search query in the search field as you type.

Comment: Just with the code above it's impossible to answer your question. What is needed is complete reproducible code of how highlight works now.

Comment: can you explain it better? Do you have a single layer with yellow dot style? Do you want the elements visible in the search list to acquire the blue dot style during the search?

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. There is a single layer with dots representing trees. As you say, I would like the elements in the search list to acquire the blue dot style during the search. Currently only one tree acquires the blue dot style after it is selected from the list.